# Characterising radially symmetric maps which are smooth at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, symmetry

This is a self-answered question. I post it here since it wasn't obvious to me. It is a follow-up of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573872/are-radially-symmetric-maps-smooth-at-the-origin) previous question of mine.

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set containing the origin, and let $h:[0,\infty] \to [0,\infty)$ be a smooth function satisfying $h(0)=0$.

Define $f:U \to \mathbb R^n$ by $ f(x)= 
 \begin{cases} \frac{h(\|x\|)}{\|x\|}x & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}$.

If we describe a point $x \in \mathbb R^n$ using its distance from the origin $r=\|x\| \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, and its  "direction" $\sigma = \frac{x}{\|x\|} \in \mathbb S^{n-1}$, then $f$ is given by
$(r,\sigma)\to  (h(r),\sigma)$.

> **Proposition:** $f$ is smooth if and only if $h$ is smooth and $h^{2k}(0)=0$ for every natural $k$.

In particular, $f$ is smooth whenever $h$ is an odd smooth function. Moreover, if $h$ is real-analytic, then $f$ is smooth if and only if $h$ is odd. (Since for real-analytic functions the condition on the derivatives implies being odd).

---

It is not hard to see that the vanishing of all the derivatives of even order is necessary. Indeed, the map $$x \mapsto f(x,0,0,\dots,0)=\frac{h(|x|)}{|x|}(x,0,0,\dots,0)=\big((h(|x|)\text{sgn}(x),0,0,\dots,0\big)$$

should be smooth. Now, it is [not hard to see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3576257/104576) that the function $x \to h(|x|)\text{sgn}(x)$ is infinitely differentiable at zero if and only if $h^{2k}(0)=0$ for every natural $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof:**

*The idea is to reduce the question to a "scalar-valued" case, i.e. to understand when smoothness of a function $x \mapsto \phi(x)$ implies the smoothness of $x \mapsto \phi(\|x\|)$.*

First, note that $f$ can be rewritten as $f(x)=F(x) \cdot x$, where $F:U \to \mathbb R$ is given by

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{h(\|x\|)}{\|x\|} & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\ h'(0) & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}.
$$

*Thus, it suffices to prove that $F$ is smooth.*

Define $g:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ by

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{h(x)}{x} & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\ h'(0) & \text{if $x=0$}\end{cases}
$$

Now, $h \in C^{\infty}$ together with $h(0)=0$, [imply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574703/h0-0-and-h-in-ck-imply-frachxx-in-ck-1) that $g \in C^{\infty}$, and $g^{m}(0)=\frac{h^{(m+1)}(0)}{m+1}$ for every natural $m$. **Thus, all the odd derivatives of $g$ vanish at zero.**

Now, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3584029/104576) implies that the map $x \mapsto g(\|x\|)=F(x)$ is smooth, as required.